# AWS Lambda and AWS CodePipeline: how to define environment variable according to stage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I have an automatic code pipeline for Lambdas and I want to define an environment variable valued dev, qlt or prod according to deployment stage.

I already have defined environment variables in serverless template as follows for region and aws account:

```
            Environment:
                Variables:
                    accountId: !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
                    region:    !Ref "AWS::Region"
```